# porque mi programa javascript no funciona

Tags: javascript

Hice un programa ultra sencillo, pero desconozco el porque no me esta funcionando.

Este es el programa:

```
"use strict"    

var precioCoche;
var dineroAhorrado;
var edad;

precioCoche = prompt("Cuanto cuesta el carro?.");
dineroAhorrado = prompt("Cuanto dinero tienes ahorrado?.");
edad = prompt("Cual es tu edad?");    

if(dineroAhorrado >= precioCoche && edad >= 18) {       
    alert("Puedes comprar el vehiculo");    
}
else {
    alert("no puedes comprar el vehiculo");
}
```

el caso es que al ejecutarlo en el navegador y colocar como precio del vehículo "1000", como dinero ahorrado "11" y como edad "18", me indica que si puedo comprar el coche ,esta accediendo al "if" a pesar de no cumplir con las condiciones .

Comment: Cuidado en comparar cadenas de texto y no números, considera usar parseInt o similares

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon en el título el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. Hay muchas preguntas con el título ¿por qué esto no funciona? y similares. Aparte, al ser descriptivo/a, logras atraer más atención a la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Porque `prompt` devuelve un `string` no un número, por lo que debes convertirlo usando `Number(ElString)`

Ejemplo:

```js
const precioCoche = Number(prompt("Cuanto cuesta el carro?."));
const dineroAhorrado = Number(prompt("Cuanto dinero tienes ahorrado?."));
const edad = Number(prompt("Cual es tu edad?"));

if(dineroAhorrado >= precioCoche && edad >= 18)
{
    
    alert("Puedes comprar el vehiculo");
}
else
{
    alert("no puedes comprar el vehiculo");
}
```

---

Un poco más de explicación:

En javascript es posible comparar cadenas (strings) esto se realiza de izquierda a derecha, evaluando cada carácter.

El algoritmo es el siguiente.

```
                 |
                 v
precioCoche    = 1 0 0 0
dineroAhorrado = 1 1
```

Compara el `1` con el `1`, al ser iguales pasa al siguiente

```
                   |
                   v
precioCoche    = 1 0 0 0
dineroAhorrado = 1 1
```

Ahora compara el `0` con el `1`, el cero es menor, entonces `precioCoche` es menor, es así como `"1000"` es menor a `"11"`

Para determinar que carácter es mayor o menor, el carácter se evalúa en según su valor en UTF-16

Comment: Tambien puede usar el signo de + en lugar de Number

`precioCoche = +prompt("Cuanto cuesta el carro?.")`

eso castearia tus valores a numericos

Ademas ten en cuenta q si no es un numero valido, precioCoche tendra el valor de NaN

Comment: @JuniorUsca Hola estimado,  `+"AAAAA"` es buena forma y  también da `NaN` cuando el string es alfabético, y es lo correcto. (no como parseInt). En este caso no requiere validación alguna porque, ` unNumero >= NaN` es false, incluso `NaN>= NaN` también es false